# Difficulties while using Tensorflow_hub and universal-sentence-encoder

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, keras-layer, tensorflow-hub, tensorflow2.x

While running the following piece of code, I get an error.
Anybody who can help me? I am using Tensorflow 2.1.0

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")

tweets = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
print(tweets.columns)
labels = tweets[['Sentiment']]
tweets = tweets[['SentimentText']]
tweets = tweets['SentimentText'].to_numpy()
embed = hub.KerasLayer("./model",  output_shape=[20],  input_shape=[],dtype=tf.string)
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
     sess.run([tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()])
     sess.run(embed(tweets))
```

I get the following error:

> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 4727, in _override_gradient_function
>       assert not self._gradient_function_map

AssertionError

[image: Error picture]

Comment: Are you using a model from tfhub.dev? If so, please add the explicit model you are using and also add an example of the data you are loading from your csv.

Comment: @kempy Thanks for your reply. My problem is solved. The piece of code doesn't have a problem. I reduce the length of my dataset and it's been working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that issue as well. It was solved by using tensorflow==2.0.0 (I was originally using tensorflow==2.1.0)

Comment: I also downgraded my TF version. I am using TF 2.0.0 now.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the Solution in Answer Section (even though it is mentioned in the Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

In this specific case, **`reducing the length of dataset has resolved the error`** but generally, it would be a good practice to provide the URL of the respective Pre-Trained Model so that it would be easy to check the properties of that model including Version Compatibility, which also improves readability.